# jest snapshots returning for attribute instead of htmlFor

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, snapshot, renderer

i am using `jest-serializer-html-string` and `preact-render-to-string` for my snapshots tests but the problem is that when i run the snapshot test update for a component that have htmlFor="" like this:

```
<Label htmlFor={input.name}>{label}</Label>
```

it generates a snapshot like this :

```
<label for="checkbox">label</label>
```

here is my jest snapshot configuration in package json:

```
"snapshotSerializers": [
  "jest-serializer-html-string"
],
```

and i am creating my snapshot tests like that:

```
it(`renders markup correctly`, () => {
    const tree = renderer(<SomeComponent />);
    expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

the problem is that `htmlFor` is converted to `for` in the snapshot file and that is causing me problems.

it was converted right before but recently, it starts to convert it to `for`, hope there is any way to keep `htmlFor` attribute as it is in the snapshots tests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems that the right behaviour is to convert `htmlFor` to for in snapshots.

so I managed to solve the problem by converting all `htmlFor` attributes I have in my components to `for` attribute.